# How to display text in front and use a image in back ground?

Tags: asp.net, css, text, background-image

I want to create a div which has background image and want to display some text on it. I have tried my self but i dont know why its not work for me. My code is as below:

```
<div style="background-image: image/test.jpg">
<asp:label id="test" runat="server" text="hello" />
</div>
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image. The address should be wrapped in `url()`:

```
style="background-image: url(image/test.jpg)"
```

Also of interest might be [the `background` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background) which allows more control over placement, repetition and fill color.

Answer (score 1):

The style is slightly wrong, it should be:

```
style="background-image: url('image/test.jpg');"
```